# Way to monitor ajax responses in firefox?

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox

I currently use the network tab in firefox that works very well.  Here I can see the exact response headers.  But I do have to reclick the each page request and then click on the response tab to see the latest results.  It would be nice to have a live feed of all ajax results (just for the same domain) that I could put onto a window in another monitor and be alerted if there were any serious errors with my ajax calls.  Does any sort of live feed/tracker system for ajax response calls (not the header...want the content), exist?

Comment: You could write one. ajaxsetup to copy request and response to another window

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!  Unfortunately in my case that is probably over my head.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) - it really makes Ajax much simpler, you can add this:

```
$(document).ajaxError(function(event, jqXHR, settings, thrownError) {
  var w = window.open("","errorwin","width=500,height=500");
  var text = "<hr/>Triggered ajaxError handler on "+settings.url;
  text += "<br/>Status:"+settings.statusCode;
  w.document.write(text);
  // w.document.close(); // only if you want a fresh report each time
});
```

Comment: That is actually a clever idea!